# Вопрос по SEO и GET

Tags: php, get, seo

Друзья, не пинайте в живот..интересует вопрос. Есть 1 страница шаблон, которая принимает GET параметры и показывает нужное содержимое. Вопрос вот в чем..как для такой страницы шаблона настроить SEO ? возможно ли это ? Будет ли робот яндекса или гугла понимать, что страницы имеют разное содержимое и правильно индексировать его

Comment: Не особо знаю что и как в СЕО, но разве такие страницы не воспринимаются как отдельные? В теории, site.d/users/1 и site.d/users/2 должны восприниматься как отдельные страницы

Comment: В теории должны..а вот как на практике неизвестно..у меня страница типа /info.php?id=АЙДИ... вот сижу и думаю, гуманно ли это

Comment: По моему скромному мнению ваша веб-страница имеет некоторое совпадение с Автоматически созданный контент [ https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/2721306 ] который есть сигнал спама.

Comment: Не думаю, что страница просмотра профиля пользователя глазами другого пользователя будет попадать под такого рода санкции т.к текст не статичный, уникальный и имеет место быть )

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В шаблоне у вас `title` и прочие мета должны соответствовать каждой странице - если Вы желаете правильной и отдельной их индексации - а если нет, то прописывайте каноникал на одну нужную.
В противном случае, нужны отличия, хотя бы с добавление (страница такая-то) в `title` и `description`.

Шаблон не означает, что мета и все остальное одно и тоже - это визуализация одна.

Насчет `id` не стоит задумываться - это нормально, хеш не будет восприниматься, а остальное - только в путь.

UPD по комменту:

Конечно - страницы отзывов, `faq` и прочего так же организованы - если используется такой принцип переходов. А иногда удобнее для пользователя часто на `ajax` смена - тогда там другие вопросы.
Ваш вариант один из оптимальных в плане индексации. Конечно, можно бы GET параметры убрать и выводить типа `/1` вместо `/?page=1`, но это уже дополнение, не существенно.

Да - и ключевики можете вообще не ставить - это сейчас лишнее. `title` и `desc` и `h1` видоизменяйте, соответственно страницам - этого достаточно.

Comment: Т.е если я просто буду так же динамически менять заголовок и описание с ключевыми, то все будет гуд ?

Comment: Добавил в ответ ответ)

Answer (score 0):

Возможно вам стоит рассмотреть вариант не динамически создаваемой страницы с ЕТ-запросами, а статической страницы, допустим фильтра. Тогда она будет и посадочной, да и контент наполнение не вызовет проблем как для вас так и для ранжирования поисковиками.

Comment: В текущем виде ваш ответ непонятен. Пожалуйста, нажмите [edit] под сообщением, чтобы добавить больше подробностей, которые помогут другим понять, как он отвечает на заданный вопрос. Вы можете найти больше информации о том, как писать хорошие ответы в [Справке](/help/how-to-answer).